# Is it possible to represent (up to a $λ^3$-null set) a 2-dimensional submanifold of $R^3$ as the graph of a $C^1$-function $f:U⊆R^2\to R$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$. Is $M$ (globally) representable as the graph of a continuous differentiable function $f:U\subseteq\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ in the sense, that $f(U)\cup N=M$ for some $\lambda^3$-null set $N$.

I know that each submanifold is *locally* representable in such a way and I'm curious whether or not a *global* representation is possible in this special scenario.

[If not, can we "cut" $M$ into mutually disjoint pieces which can be represented in this way?]

Answer (score 0):

No, just consider the sphere $S^2$ (which is indeed a manifold because $S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,;\,x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\}$). For your edit, you can show that : $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $m$ if for all $a\in M,$ it exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ an open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, a map $\Gamma\in C^1(V,\mathbb{R}^{n-m})$  and an isometry $i$ such as :
$$U\cap M=i(\{(x,\Gamma(x))\,;\,x\in V\})$$
which is the local definition you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. I want that $$M=\left\{\left(x,f(x)\right):x\in U\right\}\cup N$$ for some open set $U\subseteq\mathbb R^2$, $f\in C^1(U)$ and a $\lambda^3$-null set $N$. And if that's not possible, I want that $$M=\biguplus_nM_n$$ with $$M_n=\left\{\left(x,f_n(x)\right):x\in U_n\right\}\cup N_n$$

Comment: The "locally" that you want is the fact that you can do this kind of construction at the neighbourhood of any point of your submanifold : I say it is possible, but you have to add an isometry (how would you define your application for the sphere ? It would have to take two values in one point for the poles for example).

Comment: The poles are included in the $\lambda^3$-null set $$\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}\sin\theta\\ 0\\ \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right):\theta\in [0,\pi]\right\}$$

Comment: And again, I don't want a *local* representation. Is it possible to find a $f$ (or some $f_n$) which satisfy the equations in my first comment?

Comment: It is a new question with all these edits. It seems however true, I'll try to find something !

Comment: And note that your $2$-dimensional submanifold is a $\lambda^3-$null set !

Answer (score 0):

It is false : let's consider $$P:=\{(x,0,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,;\, x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
It is a $2-$dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a subvectorial space of dimension $2$. See as a graph, your function would have to take a uncountable number of values and so you can't even do the construction that you want (the $f_n$ would have an uncountable number of values to take too).

Comment: I tried something new, which shows the importance about the isometry in the definition.